# Reduce number of colors and get color of a single pixel

Tags: image, colors, javafx-2

Using JavaFX 2.2 I need to do the following:

1. Reduce the color of a given image (e.g. loaded using the JavaFX `image` class) to lets say 8 or 16 colors, or maybe 256 colors
2. Access the color of single pixels in the image object - OK, seems like      `Image.getPixelReader()` should do the job, so only the first question should remain

Can anyone give me some hints or code examples on this? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `image.getPixelReader()` to get a hold of the [PixelReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#getPixelReader%28%29) to access individual pixels in the image.
2. Create a [WritableImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/WritableImage.html#WritableImage%28int,%20int%29).
3. Get the [PixelWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/WritableImage.html#getPixelWriter%28%29) of the WritableImage.
4. Iterate through the pixels read from the pixel reader, run each pixel through a downscaling algorithm for it's color palette and write the downscaled pixel to the pixel writer.

After you have done this, you can display the downsampled WritableImage in an [ImageView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) or convert it to an [awt image](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html#fromFXImage%28javafx.scene.image.Image,%20java.awt.image.BufferedImage%29) and [save it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) as a png, jpg, etc.

Here is some sample code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

// displays a button with a 64 color image palette and a full color palette when pressed.
public class ButtonShadeTest extends Application {
  @Override public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    final Label response = new Label("");
    final Image originalImage = new Image("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/eponas-deeway/colobrush/128/heart-2-icon.png");
    final Image resampledImage = resample(originalImage);
    final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(resampledImage);
    final Button button = new Button("I love you", imageView);
    button.setStyle("-fx-base: coral;");
    button.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TOP);
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        if ("".equals(response.getText())) {
          response.setText("I love you too!");
          imageView.setImage(originalImage);
        } else {
          response.setText("");
          imageView.setImage(resampledImage);
        } 
      }
    });

    final VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    layout.getChildren().addAll(button, response);
    layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-padding: 10; -fx-font-size: 20;");
    stage.setTitle("Heart");
    stage.getIcons().add(originalImage);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
    stage.show();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

  // downsamples an image to a 64 color palette by only 
  // using the 2 most significant bits of color to represent
  // each of the image's pixels.
  private Image resample(Image inputImage) {
    int W = (int) inputImage.getWidth();
    int H = (int) inputImage.getHeight();
    WritableImage outputImage = new WritableImage(W, H);
    PixelReader reader = inputImage.getPixelReader();
    PixelWriter writer = outputImage.getPixelWriter();
    for (int y = 0; y < H; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < W; x++) {
        int argb = reader.getArgb(x, y);
        int a = (argb >> 24) & 0xFF;
        int r = (argb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int g = (argb >>  8) & 0xFF;
        int b =  argb        & 0xFF;

        r = r & 0xC0;
        g = g & 0xC0;
        b = b & 0xC0;

        argb = (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
        writer.setArgb(x, y, argb);
      }
    }

    return outputImage;
  }
}
// icon license: (creative commons with attribution) http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/
// icon artist attribution page: (eponas-deeway) http://eponas-deeway.deviantart.com/gallery/#/d1s7uih
```

When the heart is broken it displays with a reduced color palette, when the heart is whole it displays with a full color palette.

[image: brokenheart]
[image: mendedheart]

Comment: Thanks, but actually the downscaling algorithm is the problem, I have no clue on how to do tihs ;-)

Comment: Added a sample which includes a downscaling algorithm.

Comment: awesome, thank you for the sample code! couldn't yet test it, but will do so the next days and just wanted to say thanks for now!