# Is there a "fill" function for arbitrary shapes in javafx?

Tags: java, css, javafx, paint, javafx-8

I need to know in which way I can color the following image (PNG) by using JavaFX. This image is currently included in a ImageView of JavaFX:

[image: image with different sections]

I want to color region 1 blue, the second one red, and the last two purple. How can I do this in JavaFX? Isn't there some kind of function as in Windows Paint? (You know, the painting bucket that fills a certain area with a color between borders).

Comment: What if you add all four regions into a `Pane` and color them as desired, and set a `Circle` as the clip? This requires you to create a scene hierarchy that mirrors your image, which doesn't sound like what you want. It sounds like you want a dynamic solution that operates off of a given image, which I do not think is possible in JavaFX, at least using nodes. You might be able to do it through a `WebView` that uses a library capable of such manipulation.

Comment: That does sound like the best option indeed. How would you color an image in javaFX? I know it can be done pixel by pixel, but surely there has to be a better way?

Comment: jewelsea's answer looks better suited for your needs, as it is dynamic (and with a class named `Kraken` you can't go wrong) and the alternate approach provided sounds like a way to manipulate colors.

Answer (score 5):

**Suggested Approach**

You can use a [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm.

[image: filled]

**Sample Code**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Stack;

public class UnleashTheKraken extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        Image original = new Image(
            "http://s12.postimg.org/wofhjvy2h/image_2.jpg"
        );

        WritableImage updateable = new WritableImage(
                original.getPixelReader(),
                (int) original.getWidth(),
                (int) original.getHeight()
        );

        Kraken kraken = new Kraken(updateable, Color.WHITE);
        kraken.unleash(new Point2D(40,   40), Color.BLUE);
        kraken.unleash(new Point2D(40,  100), Color.RED);
        kraken.unleash(new Point2D(100, 100), Color.GREEN);
        kraken.unleash(new Point2D(120,  40), Color.YELLOW);

        ImageView originalView = new ImageView(original);
        ImageView filledView   = new ImageView(updateable);

        HBox layout = new HBox(10, originalView, filledView);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    class Kraken {
        private final WritableImage image;
        private final Color colorToFill;

        // tolerance for color matching (on a scale of 0 to 1);
        private final double E = 0.3;

        public Kraken(WritableImage image, Color colorToFill) {
            this.image = image;
            this.colorToFill = colorToFill;
        }

        public void unleash(Point2D start, Color color) {
            PixelReader reader = image.getPixelReader();
            PixelWriter writer = image.getPixelWriter();

            Stack<Point2D> stack = new Stack<>();
            stack.push(start);

            while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                Point2D point = stack.pop();
                int x = (int) point.getX();
                int y = (int) point.getY();
                if (filled(reader, x, y)) {
                    continue;
                }

                writer.setColor(x, y, color);

                push(stack, x - 1, y - 1);
                push(stack, x - 1, y    );
                push(stack, x - 1, y + 1);
                push(stack, x    , y + 1);
                push(stack, x + 1, y + 1);
                push(stack, x + 1, y    );
                push(stack, x + 1, y - 1);
                push(stack, x,     y - 1);
            }
        }

        private void push(Stack<Point2D> stack, int x, int y) {
            if (x < 0 || x > image.getWidth() ||
                y < 0 || y > image.getHeight()) {
                return;
            }

            stack.push(new Point2D(x, y));
        }

        private boolean filled(PixelReader reader, int x, int y) {
            Color color = reader.getColor(x, y);

            return !withinTolerance(color, colorToFill, E);
        }

        private boolean withinTolerance(Color a, Color b, double epsilon) {
            return
                    withinTolerance(a.getRed(),   b.getRed(),   epsilon) &&
                    withinTolerance(a.getGreen(), b.getGreen(), epsilon) &&
                    withinTolerance(a.getBlue(),  b.getBlue(),  epsilon);
        }

        private boolean withinTolerance(double a, double b, double epsilon) {
            return Math.abs(a - b) < epsilon;
        }
    }
}
```

**Answers to additional questions**

> But wouldn't the image be colored pixel by pixel?

Yes, that's the point, you need to shade the pixels.  Everything in computer graphics with bitmapped displays eventually comes down to coloring pixels.

> Is this an efficient way in coloring?

It's instantaneous (as far as I can tell) on the sample image you provided.  Space-wise it takes up some memory, but all such algorithms will use memory.  The sample code I provided is not the most efficient flood fill shading algorithm which could be devised (time or space wise).  The wikipedia page I linked has alternate more efficient (and more complicated) algorithms you could apply *if you needed to*.

**Alternate Approach**

If you have a cut-out stencil shape for each area, you could stack the stencils and apply [ColorAdjust](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/effect/ColorAdjust.html) effects to them (such as in: [How to change color of image in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124364/how-to-change-color-of-image-in-javafx)).  The ColorAdjust is (likely) a hardware accelerated effect.  This alternate is not a general approach though as it requires you to know the stencil shapes.

Comment: But wouldn't the image be colored pixel by pixel? Is this an efficient way in coloring?

Comment: Updated answer to address additional questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
Shape circle = new Circle(x,y,r);
Shape rect = new Rectangle(x,y,w,h);
Shape region1 = Shape.subtract(circle, rect);// to "cut" the rect away from a circle.
// You'll need to do this twice for each piece.
region1 = Shape.subtract(region1,anotherRect); 
region1.setFill(Color.BLUE);
// Then simply add your shape to a node and set it's translation.
```

The way this works is that where the rectangle overlaps the circle, that part of the circle will be removed.