# Flood fill using java Pane - JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, flood-fill, pane

Hi I am supposed to create function which would do flood fill on a **Pane** containing **Shapes** using **Java**. It is supposed to behave just like **MSPaint**, I dont need to later move rectangles Lines or other shapes. I was thinking converting Pane into Image and then work with pixels and then clear all Panes children and insert it as a image but I cant make it work.
code example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Paint extends Application {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

private Pane pane;


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    pane= new Pane();

    primaryStage.setTitle("Fill");
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane,500,600);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();


    pane.setOnMousePressed((e)->{
        doFill(e.getX(),e.getY());
    });

    //RECT 1
    Rectangle rect1=new Rectangle(1,100,200,300);
    rect1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    rect1.setStrokeWidth(2);
    rect1.setFill(Color.WHITE);

  //RECT 2
    Rectangle rect2=new Rectangle(50,150,200,400);
    rect2.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    rect2.setStrokeWidth(2);
    rect2.setFill(Color.WHITE);

    //LINE
    Line line=new Line(0,0,200,550);
    rect2.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    rect2.setStrokeWidth(2);


    pane.getChildren().addAll(rect1,rect2,line);
}

private void doFill(double eventX, double eventY){
    //**TODO**
}
```

}

Comment: dofill? is that all? dont over exert yourself

Comment: Well I hoped that at least that someone would tell me functions for converting canvas to image that you can edit and add to the pane...
You dont need to get mad at people trying to learn something...

Comment: This question is kind of similar to: [Is there a “fill” function for arbitrary shapes in javafx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983465/is-there-a-fill-function-for-arbitrary-shapes-in-javafx)  Note that arbitrary fills like this are often more closely associated with a bitmapped based system such as Canvas than a vector based system such as scene graphs (which is part of the reason why you have the additional issue of transference of the filled region to a scene graph node, for which I don't have advice on a solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got managed to do that function even though its a bit messy. So for everyone who is getting anxious over this:

```
    private void doFill(double eventX, double eventY,boolean b){

    WritableImage i=pane.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
    ArrayList<Integer> pozicie=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Character> strany=new ArrayList<Character>();
    pozicie.add((int)eventX);
    pozicie.add((int)eventY);
    int c=i.getPixelReader().getColor((int)eventX,(int)eventY).hashCode();
    if(c==usedColor.hashCode()){
        //System.out.println("same color");

        return;}
    strany.add('a');


    while(pozicie.size()!=0){
        char strana=strany.remove(0);
        int x=pozicie.remove(0);
        int y=pozicie.remove(0);
        i.getPixelWriter().setColor(x, y, usedColor);
        if(strana=='d'){
            //iba dole
            if(y<pane.getHeight()-2 && i.getPixelReader().getColor(x, y+1).hashCode()==c){
                pozicie.add(x);
                pozicie.add(y+1);
                strany.add('d');
            }
        }
        else if(strana=='u'){
            //iba hore
            if( y>100 && i.getPixelReader().getColor(x, y-1).hashCode()==c){
                pozicie.add(x);
                pozicie.add(y-1);
                strany.add('u');
            }
        }
        else{


        if(x>2 && i.getPixelReader().getColor(x-1, y).hashCode()==c){
            pozicie.add(x-1);
            pozicie.add(y);
            strany.add('l');
        }
        if(x<pane.getWidth()-2 && i.getPixelReader().getColor(x+1, y).hashCode()==c){
            pozicie.add(x+1);
            pozicie.add(y);
            strany.add('r');
        }
        if( y>101 && i.getPixelReader().getColor(x, y-1).hashCode()==c){
            pozicie.add(x);
            pozicie.add(y-1);
            strany.add('u');
        }
        if(y<pane.getHeight()-2 && i.getPixelReader().getColor(x, y+1).hashCode()==c){
            pozicie.add(x);
            pozicie.add(y+1);
            strany.add('d');
        }
        }
    }
    pane.getChildren().clear();
    pane.getChildren().add(new ImageView(i));

}
```