# JavaFX change color of ImageView

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Hello i'm trying to change the color of an ImageView when your mouse is on it(hover)

So I have a css file that contains this:

```
.cross:hover {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

And this is cross:

```
@FXML
    private ImageView cross;
```

I set the fx:id in the fxml file.

Now nothing happens when I hover over it.

This is how I add the style sheet to the scene:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Style.css").toExternalForm());
```

This is how I set the id for css on the ImageView:

```
cross.getStyleClass().add("cross");
```

So how would I change the color of the ImageView when I hover over it?

Comment: [`ImageView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#imageview) doesn't define a `-fx-background-color` css property. In most cases, an `ImageView` is completely filled by its image anyway, so it's not quite clear what you want here.

Comment: I just want to change the color of the image when you hover over it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124364/how-to-change-color-of-image-in-javafx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The color of an `ImageView` is defined by the pixel data in the image itself. You probably need to create (externally) an alternative image with the "background" changed to red, and then use the `-fx-image` CSS property of `ImageView` to change the image displayed:

```
.cross {
    -fx-image: url(images/cross.png);
}
.cross:hover {
    -fx-image: url(images/red-cross.png);
}
```

where the `images` folder has the same parent folder as the CSS file (see [CSS docs on URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeurl).)