# From RGB to HSV (Color.RGBtoHSB) in Java returns a different result

Tags: java, javafx, rgb, hsv, hsb

I'm trying to change the color of some images in JavaFX. If, for example, I insert these RGB values (185, 74, 72) I get a different result. I checked the RGB result with Paint and it is (205, 183, 183). Anyone of you knows why?

This is the code:

```
    VBox icon = new VBox();

    HBox cell = new HBox(5);

    Circle circle = new Circle(12, 12, 18);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(ICON_URL);
    ColorAdjust ca = new ColorAdjust();
    float[] hsb = new float[3];
    Color.RGBtoHSB(185, 74, 72, hsb);

    ca.setHue(hsb[0]);
    ca.setSaturation(hsb[1]);
    ca.setBrightness(hsb[2]);

    iv.setClip(circle);
    iv.setEffect(ca);

    icon.getChildren().addAll(iv);
    cell.getChildren().addAll(icon);
```

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis The image has a different color (lighter color). The RGB of modified image is (205, 183, 183) .

Comment: Could you please also provide the code where you use the above snippet?

Comment: @SubOptimal I edit the code. It's not exactly the same, but it's just an example about what I did

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code below but got white instead of blue when i set the contrast to 1.0

```
      //Instantiating the ColorAdjust class 
      ColorAdjust colorAdjust = new ColorAdjust(); 
      // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561747/from-rgb-to-hsv-color-rgbtohsb-in-java-returns-a-different-result
      //Setting the contrast value 
      colorAdjust.setContrast(1.0);     

      //Setting the hue value 
      colorAdjust.setHue(color.getHue());     

      //Setting the brightness value 
      colorAdjust.setBrightness(color.getBrightness());  

      //Setting the saturation value 
      colorAdjust.setSaturation(color.getSaturation());   

      //Applying color adjust effect to the ImageView node 
      imageView.setEffect(colorAdjust);
```

I then experimented with the code in to see that png and even svg did not work properly. So I ende up

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51726678/1497139

Comment: hmm .. this isn't an answer, or is it?

Comment: not yet - I have to add a link to what I ended up with