# Use of ColorPicker on an image in JavaFX

Tags: java, image, javafx, imageview, color-picker

I have an image in the imageview. What I want to do is add color to it. Basically it's like a layer of color on the image. So I am trying to add color to a t-shirt image using the ColorPicker and I don't know how I can do that. I've tried it along with the colorAdjust class but its giving me a different color on the tshirt than the one I've chosen from the ColorPicker.

I am using SceneBuilder, btw.

GUI

[image: GUI]

T-shirt

[image: T-shirt]

```
@FXML
private void changecolor(ActionEvent event) {      
    Color mycolor=mycolorpicker.getValue();
    label.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(mycolor,null,null)));
    Image img=new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("tshirt7.PNG"));
    imageV.setImage(img);
    ColorAdjust colorAdjust = new ColorAdjust();
    colorAdjust.setHue((mycolor.getHue()/360));
    colorAdjust.setSaturation(mycolor.getSaturation());
    colorAdjust.setBrightness(mycolor.getBrightness()-1);
   
    imageV.setEffect(colorAdjust);
}
```

I was expecting the same color on the image as the one I've chosen from ColorPicker. But the color on the tshirt is not accurate.

Comment: Please don't put pictures of code, paste the code as text into the question.

Comment: But do include the pictures necessary to replicate your issue (the original t shirt  image).

Answer (score 2):

How to color an image from a color picker.

- Ensure your `png` input image has appropriate areas of transparent color (your example t-shirt image does).
- Define a [ColorPicker](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ColorPicker.html) to pick your color.
- Bind the [picked color](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#valueProperty()) to a [MULTIPLY](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/effect/BlendMode.html#MULTIPLY) [blended](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/effect/Blend.html) [ColorInput](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/effect/ColorInput.html) effect on a [desaturated](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/effect/ColorAdjust.html#setSaturation(double)) monochrome [adjusted](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/effect/ColorAdjust.html) or [grayscaled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43068319/how-to-create-javafx-16-bit-greyscale-images/43080085#43080085) image, with the image [clipped](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#setClip(javafx.scene.Node)) by a clip defined by the image.

For more info see:

- [How to change color of image in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124364/how-to-change-color-of-image-in-javafx/18124868#18124868)

**Example**

Place the image used (I used the image provided in your question) in a resource folder with the same directory structure as the package you place the sample code in.

[image: purple]

[image: orange]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.effect.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Objects;

public class TShirtDesigner extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker();

        Image tshirtImage = new Image(
                Objects.requireNonNull(
                        TShirtDesigner.class.getResource(
                                "tshirt.png"
                        )
                ).toExternalForm()
        );

        ImageView tshirt = new ImageView(tshirtImage);
        tshirt.setClip(new ImageView(tshirtImage));

        bindImageColor(
                tshirt,
                colorPicker.valueProperty()
        );

        VBox layout = new VBox(
                10,
                colorPicker,
                tshirt
        );
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private static void bindImageColor(
            ImageView imageView,
            ObjectProperty<Color> colorProperty
    ) {
        ColorInput colorInput = new ColorInput(
                0,
                0,
                imageView.getImage().getWidth(),
                imageView.getImage().getHeight(),
                colorProperty.get()
        );
        colorInput.paintProperty().bind(
                colorProperty
        );

        ColorAdjust monochrome = new ColorAdjust();
        monochrome.setSaturation(-1.0);

        Blend colorBlend = new Blend(
                BlendMode.MULTIPLY,
                monochrome,
                colorInput
        );

        imageView.setEffect(colorBlend);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jewelsea. IT WORKED!! You've done a massive favour to me. I was stuck at this for 4 days. I am not sure how to reply a user in this platform as I am a new user but I hope it reaches you!